# how to plot a 3d circle-filled with color in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, 3d, plot, geometry

I have a function that plots a circle in 3d if given the center the normal of the circle and the radius.the function uses the plot3 command.So i want to find a way to fill that circle with some color.Also i want the circle to be transparent(i think alpha command )

Please help.

Comment: Your code would help.

Comment: Well the code it is not mine.i use the code to evaluate some numeric results.I took it from here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26588-plot-circle-in-3d/content/plotCircle3D.m

Comment: try using the "Mesh" command,I think that should help you...

Comment: Well the problem is that i can't define how to have the result that i want.I might have to use mesh,or fill3 or surf or patch command.But i don't know how.I have 3 3d points.From them i take the normal as n=cross(a-b,a-c) and i have as the center the a point, so with the function for the circle where i use the center , the normal and a normal of value 10 for example, how can i input code that fills tha circle with some color???

Comment: See my answer. If you already found `fill3`, what was so hard about giving it the right arguments?

Comment: Well you've right it's not so difficult but it wasn't my priority so i didn't searched enough.Thank you a lot for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `plotCircle3D` that you use, the line

```
plot3(points(1,:), points(2,:), points(3,:), 'r-');
```

produces a red *line* (lineseries object) in three-dimensional space. Instead, what you need is a *patch* object. The `fill3` function is one way to make a patch object, and it provides a syntax with which you can directly specify the color. E.g.

```
fill3(points(1,:), points(2,:), points(3,:), 'b')
```

colors the circle shape in blue. You can then manipulate the patch object to set further properties like transparency. Equivalently, `fill3` accepts properties to be specified as additional arguments:

```
fill3(points(1,:), points(2,:), points(3,:), 'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5)
```

makes a blue circle shape that is half transparent.

Just modify the function to use `fill3` instead of `plot3`.

Comment: Thank you, i have what i want now!